# create table view in 5.0 OS in blackberry?

Tags: uitableview, blackberry

I am working on a UI based application in which I need to show data in tabular formate in 2x2 table, means 2 rows and 2 column.

I had seen the table view class use of Blackberry OS 6.0 but my application will run on 5.0 OS too.
Please guide me to generate a custom table view in blackberry.

Thanx in advance...!

Comment: did u try grid layout http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11958/Create_grid_layout_877557_11.jsp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code as a guide.

```
    GridFieldManager grid = new GridFieldManager(2,2,0); //First parameter for row,second for column

    grid.add(new LabelField("Column 1")//Give a heading to your grid field
    {
       public void paint(Graphics graphics)
       {
         graphics.setColor(Color.RED);
         super.paint(graphics);
       }
     });
    grid.add(new LabelField("Column 2")
    {
       public void paint(Graphics graphics)
       {
         graphics.setColor(Color.RED);
         super.paint(graphics);
       }
     });


    grid.setColumnPadding(30);
    grid.setRowPadding(30);
    add(grid);
```

You can also refer in BB docs for an example.